How should I handle exposure to different topics between participants in a panel dataset using Stata?
I'm looking to analyze data using Stata in which participants were randomly assigned to read 2 out of 4 possible topics. After reading a topic, participants were exposed to five levels of treatment (within-subjects design). For each treatment, participants responded to six measures (continuous variables).
Below is an example of the data structure:
[CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(id participant topic treatment measure1 measure2 measure3 measure4 measure5 measure6 treatment1 treatment2 treatment3 treatment4 treatment5)
 1 1 2 1 3 2 3 3 3 1 1 0 0 0 0
 2 1 2 2 7 1 1 1 1 7 0 1 0 0 0
 3 1 2 3 7 7 1 1 6 6 0 0 1 0 0
 4 1 2 4 3 4 3 3 3 4 0 0 0 1 0
 5 1 2 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 1
 6 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 7 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
 8 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
 9 1 3 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
10 1 3 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
11 2 1 1 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 0 0 0 0
12 2 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 1 0 0 0
13 2 1 3 5 5 5 5 6 6 0 0 1 0 0
14 2 1 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 1 0
15 2 1 5 4 4 4 5 4 4 0 0 0 0 1
16 2 3 1 6 4 6 5 6 6 1 0 0 0 0
17 2 3 2 7 7 7 7 7 7 0 1 0 0 0
18 2 3 3 6 6 6 6 5 6 0 0 1 0 0
19 2 3 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 0 0 0 1 0
20 2 3 5 7 7 7 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
21 3 3 1 4 1 5 1 4 3 1 0 0 0 0
22 3 3 2 1 1 3 3 4 4 0 1 0 0 0
23 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 4 4 0 0 1 0 0
24 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 0 0 0 1 0
25 3 3 5 1 4 4 3 4 4 0 0 0 0 1
26 3 4 1 4 3 4 1 4 3 1 0 0 0 0
27 3 4 2 5 4 1 4 3 2 0 1 0 0 0
28 3 4 3 6 4 1 1 3 7 0 0 1 0 0
29 3 4 4 5 7 4 1 4 7 0 0 0 1 0
30 3 4 5 3 4 1 1 4 4 0 0 0 0 1
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
end
[/CODE]

This is the code I'm currently using to gauge the effects of the five treatment levels on an outcome (measure1). Because the same participants responded to the same questions twice, I am treating this data as panel data. I assigned 'participant' as a fixed-effect to mitigate non-independence of responses.
xtset participant
xtreg measure1 i.treatment1 i.treatment2 i.treatment3 i.treatment4 i.treatment5, fe 

But I'm unsure how to account for the effect of topic on participants' response to each level of treatment, especially because participants were randomly assigned to 2 topics. I do not have information on which topic participants responded to first and am worried about qualitative differences between each topic impacting responses, or there being ordering effects.
Should topic be assigned as a random-effect? I've considered doing something like this:
mixed measure1 treatment || topic:

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I'm also wondering if there's a linear model I could use that accounts for both participant fixed effects and topic in the same model.
What would be the best way to handle this? I apologize for any vagueness and would be happy to provide more information.

How many participants do you have in total?

I have 154 participants.

With your design and data, you could go a number of ways with the model. Every subject was exposed to each of the 5 treatments and they were exposed to those treatments under two of five topics. So you have within-person information on the effect of treatment type and topic type. To your question of "how to account for the effect of topic on participants' response to each level of treatment," you can do this via an interaction between topic and treatment.
Staying with your fixed effect approach:
xtreg measure1 i.treatment##i.topic, i(participant) fe
testparm i.topic             // main effect of topic
testparm i.treatment         // main effect of treatment
margins treatment#topic
marginsplot, xdimension(treatment)

You can also estimate this as a random effects model (chage fe option to re in your xtreg call), which uses both within- and between-person information in computing the parameter estimates. Whether that is appealing to you depends on a number of factors, including your field, your tolerance for the assumptions of random effects vs. fixed effects, etc.
Note in a random effects framework, you can include topic as a random intercept, but I'm not sure what you want out of topic. Do you want a parameter estimate for the topic effect? If so, then you probably want to include it as a predictor rather than a random intercept. Note that if you wanted it as the latter, you would need to move over to mixed and run a cross-classified model given that treatments and topics are crossed:
mixed measure1 i.treatment || _all:R.topic || participant:

Another option is to use ANOVA:
* Fixed effects ANOVA
anova measure1 i.treatment##i.topic participant 

* Random effects ANVOA
anova measure1 i.treatment##i.topic / participant 

You can run the margins command for these ANOVA models. And if you wanted pair-wise comparisons, us pwcompare with whichever of the predictors you are interested in (or the interaction term).
